# Ranap ErrorIndication

Tags: wireshark, gsm, 3g

I am new to telecom domain

I am trying to encode and decode the ranap errorIndication message.

but the specification specifies that

**Procedure Code is to be used
if Criticality Diagnostics is part
of Error Indication procedure,
and not within the response
message of the same
procedure that caused the
error.**

So if I include the procedure code of the failing message in the errorIndication message.Then the wireshark shows the errorIndication as the SACK of the failed message.

So I want to know how we can include the procedure code of the failing message in the errorIndication so that Wireshark should treat the message correctly.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at [3GPP TS 25.413 (RANAP signalling)](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/25413.htm) shows that Criticality Diagnostics (9.2.1.35) is part of the Error Indication message (9.1.41).

In section 8.27, the spec says

> The Error Indication procedure is initiated by a node to report detected errors in one incoming message, provided they cannot be reported by an appropriate failure message.

The definition for Procedure Code that you quoted in the question, makes it clear that the Procedure Code refers to a message that is NOT being replied to with the Error Indication.

In the Error Indication (section 9.1.41), there is also no code that refers to the message that caused the Error Indication.

The Error Indication information elements are

Message Type
Cause
Criticality Diagnostics (includes the Procedure Code that is causing the error)
CN Domain indicator
Global RNC ID
Global CN ID
Extended RNC ID

So, my conclusion, based on your description, is that I think Wireshark may have interpreted the spec wrongly.  Wireshark seems to be looking for a message to which the Error Indicator is a reply.

But the Procedure Code is only supposed to tell you which message **caused the error and should be re-sent**.  It's not supposed to tell you that the Error Indicator is a reply to that particular message.

Apologies if I am slandering Wireshark - if anyone comes up with an answer that proves me wrong, I will happily delete this post.  Maybe you should ask this question on the [Wireshark forum](http://ask.wireshark.org/).  I couldn't see anything like the issue you describe among the questions there.